Why is it I have set the equalizer for an MKV file and in streaming it to a TV in VLC, but the TV appears to not use the equalizer settings?
I have film files of various codecs which I play with VLC on a PC.
I can modify the playback with VLC equalizer (saving the settings) but when I use 'render' to send the film to Chromecast on a TV I do not get the equalizer effects.
How can I stream (or re-record) with the equalizer effects running?
